# How do I find the information I need to get the perimeter of the largest right triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How do I use the properties of trisecting lines to find the perimeter of triangle $BDC$?

> Darcy mounted a motion sensor so it would light a path to the door on her deck. If you know $AB = 10\ \text{feet}$, and $BE$ and $BD$ trisect $\angle ABC$, what is the perimeter of the deck area to the right of the beam of light?

Later on in the problem it tells me to use trigonometric ratios for the special $30\ 60\ 90$ triangle, so I assume it wants me to use those.

Help?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to find the area of triangle BDC?

Comment: AEB is a 30 60 90 triangle with height 10 short side AE and hypot AE.  ADB is a 30 60 90 triangle with height AD, short side 10.  And hypot AE.  So you should be able to find AE AD BE and BD and thus the perimeter of the triangle.

Answer (score 1):

In a 30-60-90 right (special) angled triangle, the lengths are in the ratio $1: \sqrt 3 : 2$.

In your figure, there are three triangles of such type. Use ratios on similar triangles to calculate each length.

For example, in $\triangle BCD, BD : CD = 2 : 1$. Therefore $BD = 20$.